# Javascript modules import fails

Tags: javascript, export, importerror, es6-modules

I'm trying enter code here in to execute an imported module from a HTML page. I get to see that it's partially getting executed. I need help. My code files are test.html, main.js and say.js. These files are produced below in the same order.

`test.html`:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="sayHi('Manish')">
 </body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
import { sayHi } from './say.js';
sayHi('MK');
```

`say.js`:

```
export function sayHi(user) {
alert('Hello, { $user }');}
```

[This code partially executes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZFqj.png)

Then after this partial execution, it gives an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHi is not defined
>
> at onload (test.html:7)

The picture of the error is as shown below:

[This is the error that says sayHi function is not recognized. Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVLI0.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you seem to be a bit of a beginner with this stuff, can I ***strongly*** recommend using one of the standard, reasonable forms of indentation and bracing, not what's used in the question, in particular: 1. Indent the code of a function, 2. Don't put the closing brace on the same line as the last statement in a block. #1 makes it much easier to read the code, and #2 makes it **much** easier to edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about modules is that top level declarations, etc., in them **don't** create globals. One of the bad things about `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers is that the functions you call with them have to be globals. Your `sayHi` isn't a global, so `onload="sayHi('Manish')"` fails because it doesn't have access to `sayHi`.

Which is a good thing.

Instead, just call the function from `main.js`:

```
import { sayHi } from './say.js';
sayHi('MK');
sayHi('Manish');
```

Because module scripts are automatically deferred until the end of HTML processing, you know that won't happen until all the HTML is loaded. This is covered by a great graphic in [this section of the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element), duplicated here:

[image]

If you want to wait longer, until the `load` event (which doesn't fire until all images and such are loaded), use a modern event handler to do that:

```
import { sayHi } from './say.js';
sayHi('MK');
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    sayHi('Manish');
});
```

If you need information from the element you hooked the event on, use a traditional function and access the element as `this`, or accept the `event` parameter and use `event.currentTarget` (you can also use `event.target` for the element that the event targets, which could be within the element you hooked the event on). So for instance, suppose you have:

```
<button type="button" data-name="Manish" id="btn-say-hi">
```

you could have:

```
import { sayHi } from './say.js';
document.getElementById("btn-say-hi").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sayHi(this.getAttribute("data-name"));
});
```

---

Also note that as Vikas Saini pointed out your `say.js` is using a string literal instead of a template literal (and although he/she didn't mention it, also has the wrong syntax for a substitution), so you'll actually see the text `Hello { $user }` instead of seeing `Hello MK` or `Hello Manish`. Either use a template literal with the correct form of substitution (`${user}`, not `{ $user }`):

```
export function sayHi(user) {
    alert(`Hello, ${user}`);
}
```

or simple string concatenation:

```
export function sayHi(user) {
    alert("Hello, " + user);
}
```

Comment: HI Mr. Crowder, your code works. However, I'd like to know if I can pass a parameter externally from the HTML file to the main.ja file. This will ease out a lot many things for me. Would really appreciate if you can guide me in this regard. The main idea is to pass a parameter to the function being called so that it behaves accordingly.

Comment: @ManishDeshpande - If you need information about the element the event occurred on, use a traditional (non-arrow) function and use `this` to access the element you hooked the event on with `addEventListener`. (Or you can accept the `event` parameter and use `event.currentTarget` to get the same element.) You can put `data-*` attributes on the element that the function can access. I'm out for about 30 minutes but I can add an example of that.

Comment: @ManishDeshpande - Added.

Answer (score 1):

Classic case of String interpolation

Use

```
export function sayHi(user) { alert(`Hello, ${user}`);}
```

Notice ` in place of ' or "

Reference https://campushippo.com/lessons/how-to-do-string-interpolation-with-javascript-7854ef9d

For the Error, bind the window to load

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    sayHi('testing');
});
```

Comment: *"Edit: Not able to post ` as its getting replaced in that code but just replace ' with the mentioned symbol"* Use the `{}` button on the toolbar. Also the [?] button.

Comment: Note that although this is *also* wrong in the OP's code, it is not the cause of the error the OP asked about.

Comment: Thanks much Vikas, after the changes that I made based on your solution, am able to see that say('MK") in the main.js fires, but the HTML pages errors out with the message: Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHi is not defined
    at test.html:10. <br> That means that the function is not visible or is out of scope in the HTML page. Where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Basically my objective was to pass some parameter from the HTML script to the main.js file. I have got the required after both of you have given me hints, especially Vikas Saini. The suggestion of adding an event listener in the main.js file helped a lot. Thanks much. I'm posting the corrected and the latest code files for the benefit of ES6 beginners like me.

### The test.html file contents

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="btn-say-hi"label="fill here" placeholder="Fill in here and click"/>
</body>
</html>
```

### The main.js file contents

```
import { sayHi } from './say.js';
document.getElementById("btn-say-hi").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sayHi(this.value);
});
```

### The say.js file contents

```
export function sayHi(user) { alert(`Hello, ${user}`); }
```

Kindly note: All these files are in the same directory/folder. I could change the text item value and could get the required execution based on my inputs.

Thanks much to T.J. Crowder and a **special thanks to Vikas Saini** for the code snippet pertaining to adding the event listener. That was a golden suggestion.

Thanks much guys.
Regards
Manish.